# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}f=0$ Prove that there is a number $z$ in $[a, b]$ such that $f(z)=0$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}f=0$ Prove that there is a number $z$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(z)=0$.
Show by an example that the continuity assumption is necessary.

This seems simple but for some reason I'm not getting it. Can I get some assistance?

Comment: Hint: Is there a point $x$ in the interval so that $f(x)\geq 0$? Is that a point $y$ so that $f(y) \leq 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of the mean value theorem of integration. Since $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, there exists maximum/minimum values $M$ and $m$ (respectively). Then $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, so integrating gives
$$m(b-a)\leq\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\leq M(b-a),$$
and we divide by $b-a$ to obtain
$$m\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\leq M.$$
Now $m = f(c_1)$ for some $c_1$ and $M = f(c_2)$ for some $c_2$ since $f$ *attains* its max/min. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $z$ in between $c_1$ and $c_2$ (and hence in the interval) such that $f(z)$ is equal to the middle term in our inequality, i.e.,
$$f(z)(b-a) = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0\implies f(z) = 0.$$

Comment: I am afraid you have missed $dx$ in your integral. I'm adding it to your post if you don't mind.

Comment: It's actually not uncommon to drop the "$(x)\,dx$" when the context is understood, but I've went ahead and approved the edits. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\ne 0$, for any $x\in[a,b]$ then either $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ or $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in [a, b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Rm: $f(x),g(x)\in R[a,b]$ (Riemann integrable), if $\forall x\in [a,b], f(x)<g(x)$, then
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx< \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$$
and vice versa.
Now that if there is no such $z$ that $f(z)=0$, then $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$, $\forall x\in[a,b]$. Take the first case for example, according to the Rm
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx> \int_{a}^{b} 0 dx=0$$
That contradicts $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=0$. And likewise, $f(x)<0$ will also lead to such contradiction.
Therefore the hypothesis that "there is no such $z$ that $f(z)=0$" doesn't hold, say, $\exists z \in [a,b]$ such that $f(z)=0$. QED.